# Using sass lighten functions with variable not working

Tags: css, sass

I am using SASS in my project with

Here if my variables code

```
:root, [data-theme="default"] {
    --text-color: #383143;
}
$text-color: var(--text-color);
```

i am using that variable with lighten function like bellow,

```
body {
    color: lighten($text-color, 10%);
}
```

I am getting the following error,

> Error: argument `$color` of `lighten($color, $amount)` must be a color
>              on line 10 of assets/scss/base/typography.scss, in function `lighten`

How can I use lighten function with that variable? I need to use **--text-color: #383143;** that format for the color switcher purpose.

Comment: You cannot, SASS doesn't see CSS variables, CSS comes after

Comment: The SASS can only accept the color value #383143 in the lighten function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use SASS variables in CSS variables as those are compiled before CSS is running. To solve this you could move the CSS variable to be defined by SASS, like this

```
$text-color: #383143;
:root, [data-theme="default"] {
  --text-color: #{$text-color};
}
```

Comment: It does not return the color value. 
[data-theme=dark] {
    --text-color: $text-color;
}

Comment: Oh, forgot that you have to surround it with #{}. See my updated answer, or read more here: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/css-vars

Comment: Do you know how to use lighten function in that variable format var(--text-color)?

Comment: Lighten is also run on Sass compilation. So what you would do is pass the $text-color instead of the CSS var, as that variable is not available in Sass